# Cannot get out of infinite loop

Tags: python

The problem I am trying to solve is go through a list.  In this list, if there is the letter "a", give me all those words.  Once I have done that, pose the same question again so I go choose the letter "m".  Once I type "quit" give me the final list.

Here is the code I have so far, but I get stuck in an infinite loop.  I am missing something small that prevents me from asking the same question.  When I type the below code, I get an infinite loop.

```py
list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel", "elephant", "python", "giraffe", "tiger", "gorilla"]
     
new_list = []

y = input("Pick an orange letter that you want to check against.  Type quit to exit  ") 


while y != "quit":
    for x in list:
        if y in x:
            new_list.append(x)
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the question a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking for new input in your loop. Therefore, you are not updating your value of `y` necessary to exit the loop.

Something like the below should work.

```py
list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel", "elephant", "python", "giraffe", "tiger", "gorilla"]
 
new_list = []

y = input("Pick an orange letter that you want to check against.  Type quit to exit  ") 


while y!= "quit":
 for x in list:
     if y in x:
      new_list.append(x)
 print(new_list)
 y = input("Pick an orange letter that you want to check against.  Type quit to exit  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered you own question: you did not let the user type the question again!
Correct the code like this:

```
list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel", "elephant", "python", "giraffe", "tiger", "gorilla"]

new_list = []

y = input("Pick an orange letter that you want to check against.  Type quit to exit  ") 


while y!= "quit":
 for x in list:
  if y in x:
   new_list.append(x)
 y = input("Pick an orange letter that you want to check against.  Type quit to exit  ") 
 print(new_list)
```

Comment: I spent 3 days on this and I got my question answered in 10 mins.  THank you all so much.  It makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have some repeated words unless you add line 4 below:

```
while y!= "quit":
 for x in list:
     if y in x:
         if x not in new_list:
            new_list.append(x)
```